# Assign dataraeder value to dataset in asp.net

Tags: .net, asp.net, ado.net

I want to assign `DataReader` value to a `DataSet`, is there any method which helps to do this?

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way is using `DataAdapter` and pass your `DataSet` to its `Fill` methods like this

```
MyDataAdapter.Fill(MyDataSet);
```

if your `DataSet` contains more than one table you can state which table you will Fill like this

```
MyDataAdapter.Fill(MyDataSet,"TableName");
```

if you want to use the `DataReader` you will have to loop over each record and each cell then create new `DataRow` that will be added to a `DataTable` then add this table to your `DataSet`

Answer (score 1):

```
SqlDataReader dr;
//Fill the Reader
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
ds.Load(dr, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges,dt);
```